# is there a difference between vector.size() = 0 and vector.empty()?

Tags: c++, size

I am writing a code in c++ and I want to know when we are calling a vector
is there any difference between if the `vector.size() = 0` or `vecor.empty();`
I am confused.

```
if (Vector.size()>1000)
    if (!Vector.empty())
        std::cout << "I am Here " ;
```

I wonder to know in order to reach the third line applying the second line makes sense? can we say if the first line is true then we have a vector which is not empty?

Comment: No, the documentation says "Returns whether the vector is empty (**i.e. whether its size is 0**)." http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/empty/

Comment: But imagine you change the container for another one when this is not the case, for whatever reason...

Comment: Your post shows no research effort.

Comment: Well, `vector.size() = 0` will be a bug while misspelling `empty` will be a compiler error ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver `vector.size() = 0;` is also [a compiler error](https://godbolt.org/z/EBHQLo).

Comment: Doh.  Forgot it returns a temporary.

Answer (score 1):

There is not difference in observable behavior.

But there can be a difference in the implementation details.

For example if the `vector` is implemented with a counter, then `size()` can just return the counter.

`empty()` can check whether:

```
vector.counter == 0
```

And if you call `size() == 0`, that will be the same as the `empty()` implementation. No difference

But in the case of the `vector` implemented by 2 pointers `begin_ptr` and `end_ptr`, then `size()` has to be computed `end_ptr - begin_ptr`.

So checking `size() == 0` will calculate the size and then compare with 0.

Whereas `empty()` can just check:

```
begin_ptr == end_ptr
```

`empty()` will be implemented in whatever way the implementer thinks will work the best in the general case.

So I would recommend to call `empty()` when it is needed.

If you first check if `size() > 1000` and then check if it's not `empty()`. Then logically that's a useless check.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty

Comment: What do you mean *There can be a difference*?  What could possible be different?

Comment: @NathanOliver If vector implements a counter, then `empty` can check if the counter is `== 0` . If vector doesn't implement a counter, instead implements `size` by the difference of `begin` and `end`, then `empty` can check if `begin==end`.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk A difference in implementation doesn't mean an *actual* difference in behavior or performance. A difference in standard container implementation decision certainly doesn't make a difference for higher level concerns like maintainability or portability for it's user. So I don't really see what conclusion the first part of this answer is trying to reach.

Comment: Okay, but the behavior of doing `if(vector.szie() == 0)` and `if(vector.empty())` is exactly the same.

Comment: "difference" as in "different observable behavour" definitely no. "difference" as in "different implementation details" yes, why not, but then you could also say that there is a difference between `vector.size() == 0;` and `vector.size() == 0;` :P

Comment: Updated the answer with comments. Does it explain better?

Comment: tbh I think "there is no difference whatsoever" would be better, but thats just my different point of view of what makes a "better" answer. I dont really understand your reasoning to recommend using `empty` based on implementation details. `size` is guaranteed to be of constant complexity and so is `empty`. I would agree to readability and expressiveness, but I think arguing about performance is slightly misleading